# Using Git Repositories cross platform for mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, git, repository, repository-pattern

I was wondering how I should structure my git repo(s) when dealing with native  cross platform  mobile apps.

**this is the issue:** I have made a native mobile app for IOS and Android, with that comes a small backend to link to databases, written in php.

what is the most efficient way to manage this project.
should i make  **multiple repos**, so i can store each fragment of the project separate.
or **1 big repo** with all code and project files for this cross platfom mobile app?

Comment: The php component, is it common for both iOS and Android?

Comment: yes, is used in both platforms to connect to databases and execute basic functions

Answer (score 1):

Git submodule concept designed for your needs.
Main idea is that you could organise each project as git submodule of main git repo. Git submodules doc: 
http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 0):

If creating new and separate repositories for each 3 of them is not a problem, then I would vote for separate repositories. 
It would be cleaner to manage, and you will have better compartmentalization. You can share only the required codebases with the people that you want to grant access to.

If, however, creating separate ones cost you more money, you can go ahead and create just one repository and have 3 folders in it, one for iOS, 2nd for Android and the 3rd for your php code.